# Div height changing with new media screen CSS

Tags: css

The page [here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/index.html) has a fixed header and header highlight box-shadow with 3ems of padding added to the body, but when changing this to relative positioning for laptop resolutions so they can see more of the page, the header text moves down slightly with the new CSS and the header highlight is 1px too high so you can't see it.

It's quite subtle, but you can notice it.  Here's the new CSS:

```
body {
  padding-top: 0;
  }

.headerHighlight, .header {
  position: relative;
  }

#main-content {
  padding-top: 0.7em;
  }
```

Any ideas appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The `.headerHighlight` element should be inside of the `.header` element:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="headerHighlight"></div>
</div>
```

The `.headerHighlight` element needs to be positioned absolutely, and the `.header` element must remain positioned relatively:
    .header {
        position: relative;
    }

```
.headerHighlight {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```